# Google Analytics: Report pageviews of posts older than N days, and younger than N days

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I help manage a site that has multiple (~100) blogs.  I need to be able to report on pageviews per blog and segment the past months traffic into X number of visits to posts published within the past 30 days, and Y number of visits to posts older than 30 days.  Does anyone know how to accomplish this?

Example Report Row:

```
blog-name/url, total # visits last month, # visits to posts <= 30 days old, # visits to posts > 30 days old
```

I wonder if implementing a custom variable that's the date published would be the right way to start doing this; but then I'm not sure if that's over-complicating something that could possibly be built-in?

Answer (score 0):

Are there publish dates in the URL? If so, you can create regex's that capture those URL's (based on the time period you need). Alternatively, if you're running the new Universal Analytics, you could try the new dimension widening (basically, uploads of lookup tables) in combination with the creation of a custom dimension.

https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/3191417?hl=en

Comment: Thanks for the response Tom.  Yes the URL format is /yyyy/mm/, so I can create dashboard widgets that filter based on that, but the dashboard widgets' filters aren't dynamic...I'd have to go to each widget and manually change the URL filter's date range.  I made some test widgets for a small site I have [here](http://drop.bigdawggi.com/sSVW/qSAHW5IS).  Is there a better reporting area, that can use dynamic filters based on the dates selected at the dashboard level?

Comment: @bigdawggi So, you can create segments that get you what you need for a given month... but it would be very time consuming to do this on an ongoing basis. Have you taken a look at Supermetrics Data Grabber (formerly GA Data Grabber)? You should be able to pull down this data and create what you need in Excel... Alternatively, you can take a look at the GA report API (https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/reference)

Comment: Thanks Tom, yeah it seems that GA doesn't have the sort of reporting ability for this type of information, so I'll need to use the API so I can use the dynamic regex patterns to match the date-based URL pattern.  Not a big deal, but just wanted to make sure I wasn't missing something that was built in.

Answer (score 0):

I would write an array, use the wp_user_query, then create a filtered UA profile with the terms that are listed (x number of page view to posts in the last 30 days) and (x number of page vists to posts over the lifetime of the profile.)

This process is labor intensive to do for 100+ existing blogs; however you might be able to build a plugin and use the  ga.js library (_gaq push) to build a plugin to create the views as defined in your post
(https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/methods/gaJSApi_gaq_)

and pull with the analytics.js library for the google charts tool api

(https://developers.google.com/analytics/solutions/articles/gdataAnalyticsCharts).

Draw the GA chart in the super admin dashboard of wordpress multisite.

Comment: Is there a resource for the creation of a "filtered UA profile"?  Also I'm just a little confused still.  Are you proposing that I get the posts that have been published in last 30 days and then query via the GA API for those posts; and then essentially do subtraction (total minus the last 30 day post views) to get the views of the remaining (i.e., non-30 day posts)?